# Google Maps Direction API Android Studio - Adding an additional waypoint in between of the route

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-directions-api

I am working on my project trying to add a waypoint in between of the route that I generated from my Location to Destination, short (point A to point B). I am not able to do this due to only a singular marker added to the calculateDirections() method and calculated.
How program works:
Location is added to the map, the first point is added when the user searches for the location in an autocomplete view and it gets calculated straight away showing the route to the user. Once this is done, user is able to click anywhere on the map to add an additional marker.
The problem:
Once the additional marker is added, the program just reroutes everything to the new point leaving the initial point. What can I do to fix this issue, here is the essential code for autocomplete method, calculate route and calculate popylines:

```
    mSearchText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            
            Intent intent = new 
            Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(AutocompleteActivityMode.OVERLAY,     
            fields)
                    .build(MapsActivity.this);
            startActivityForResult(intent, AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
            hideSoftKeyboard();
            return false;
        }
    });
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable     
Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data);
            Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
            String searchString = place.getName();
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this,     
            Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> list;

            try {
                list = geocoder.getFromLocationName(searchString, 1);
                if (list.size()> 0){

                    Address address = list.get(0);
                    LatLng latLng = new         
                    LatLng(address.getLatitude(),address.getLongitude());
                    
                    
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,15));
                    MarkerOptions marker = new         
            MarkerOptions().position(latLng);
                    calculateDirections(marker);
                    //add on map click listener and add an additional marker
                    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new     
                    GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
                        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                            List<LatLng> list = new ArrayList<>();
                            list.add(latLng);
                            // Add some markers to the map, and add a data                 
                            object to each marker
                           MarkerOptions marker2 = new         
                           MarkerOptions().position(latLng);
                           calculateDirections(marker2);

                        }
                    });

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "geoLocate: IOException: " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (resultCode == AutocompleteActivity.RESULT_ERROR) {
            Status status = Autocomplete.getStatusFromIntent(data);
            Log.i(TAG, status.getStatusMessage());
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // The user canceled the operation.
        }
        return;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
private void calculateDirections(MarkerOptions marker){
    Log.d(TAG, "calculateDirections: calculating directions.");
    ArrayList<MarkerOptions> markers = new ArrayList<>(2);
    markers.add(marker);
    for (int i = 0; i < markers.size(); i++) {
        dest1 = markers.get(0);
        com.google.maps.model.LatLng destination = new 
        com.google.maps.model.LatLng(
                dest1.getPosition().latitude,
                dest1.getPosition().longitude
        );
        if (markers.size() > 1){
            dest2 = markers.get(1);
            DirectionsApiRequest directions = new 
            DirectionsApiRequest(mGeoApiContext);
            directions.alternatives(true);
            directions.origin(
                    new com.google.maps.model.LatLng(
                            userPosition.getPosition().latitude,
                            userPosition.getPosition().longitude
                    )
            );
            directions.optimizeWaypoints(true);
            directions.waypoints(
                    new com.google.maps.model.LatLng(
                            dest2.getPosition().latitude,
                            dest2.getPosition().longitude
                    )
            );
            Log.d(TAG, "calculateDirections: destination: " + 
            destination.toString());
            directions.destination(destination).setCallback(new 
            PendingResult.Callback<DirectionsResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DirectionsResult result) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "calculateDirections: routes: " + 
                    result.routes[0].toString());
                    Log.d(TAG, "calculateDirections: duration: " + 
                    result.routes[0].legs[0].duration);
                    Log.d(TAG, "calculateDirections: distance: " + 
                    result.routes[0].legs[0].distance);
                    Log.d(TAG, "calculateDirections: geocodedWayPoints: " 
                    + result.geocodedWaypoints[0].toString());
                    addPolylinesToMap(result);

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "calculateDirections: Failed to get 
                directions: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            DirectionsApiRequest directions = new 
            DirectionsApiRequest(mGeoApiContext);
            directions.alternatives(true);
            directions.origin(
                    new com.google.maps.model.LatLng(
                            userPosition.getPosition().latitude,
                            userPosition.getPosition().longitude
                    )
            );
            Log.d(TAG, "calculateDirections: destination: " + 
            destination.toString());
            directions.destination(destination).setCallback(new 
            PendingResult.Callback<DirectionsResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DirectionsResult result) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "calculateDirections: routes: " + 
                result.routes[0].toString());
                    Log.d(TAG, "calculateDirections: duration: " + 
                result.routes[0].legs[0].duration);
                    Log.d(TAG, "calculateDirections: distance: " + 
                result.routes[0].legs[0].distance);
                    Log.d(TAG, "calculateDirections: geocodedWayPoints: " 
                + result.geocodedWaypoints[0].toString());
                    addPolylinesToMap(result);

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "calculateDirections: Failed to get 
                directions: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

private void addPolylinesToMap(final DirectionsResult result){
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "run: result routes: " + result.routes.length);

            //check if there are any polylines selected and remove the old 
            one before the new
            //one is selected
            if(mPolylinesData.size() > 0){
                for (PolylineData polylineData: mPolylinesData){
                    polylineData.getPolyline().remove();
                }
                mPolylinesData.clear();
                mPolylinesData = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            double duration = 999999;
            for(DirectionsRoute route: result.routes){
                Log.d(TAG, "run: leg: " + route.legs[0].toString());
                // Get all the lines on checklist by calling decoder path
                List<com.google.maps.model.LatLng> decodedPath = 
            PolylineEncoding.decode(route.overviewPolyline.getEncodedPath());
                // Adding new array list by adding all the lines
                List<LatLng> newDecodedPath = new ArrayList<>();

                // This loops through all the LatLng coordinates of ONE 
                polyline.
                for(com.google.maps.model.LatLng latLng: decodedPath){
                    newDecodedPath.add(new LatLng(
                            latLng.lat,
                            latLng.lng
                    ));
                }
                Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(new 
                PolylineOptions().addAll(newDecodedPath));
                
            polyline.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), 
            R.color.darkGrey));
                polyline.setClickable(true);
                mPolylinesData.add(new PolylineData(polyline, 
                route.legs[0]));

                // Measure time in seconds of all trip durations and 
                select the shortest duration
                double tempDuration = route.legs[0].duration.inSeconds;
                if(tempDuration < duration){
                    duration = tempDuration;
                    onPolylineClick(polyline);
                }

            }
        }
    });
}
```